# Mejorar el paso de condicionales a Prolog

Tags: condiciones, prolog, pseudocódigo

Deseo saber como realizar el siguiente pseudocodigo en Prolog:

```
SI PELOTA= 'NO' ENTONCES LIBRO'SI'
SI MANDO='NO' ENTONCES LIBRO ='SI'
SI PELOTA = 'SI' Y ARCO = 'SI' ENTONCES LIBRO = 'NO'
SI LIBRO= 'SI' ENTONCES ACCION="LEER LIBROS"
SI BASKET= 'SI' ENTONCES ACCION="JUGAR BASKET"
SI LIBRO='NO' Y BASKET='NO' ENTONCES ACCION="DORMIR"
```

Y lo siguiente son las clausulas que consideré, aunque no uso variables, sino paso valores.

```
predicates
nondeterm es_principal(symbol,symbol).
nondeterm es_objeto(symbol,symbol).
nondeterm accion(string).

clauses
%REGLAS
es_principal(libro,si):-es_objeto(pelota,no). %REGLA_1
es_principal(libro,si):-es_objeto(mando,no).  %REGLA_2
es_principal(libro,no):-es_objeto(pelota,si),es_objeto(mando,si). %REGLA_3
accion("Leer libros"):-es_principal(libro,si). %REGLA_4
accion("Jugar basket"):-es_principal(basket,si). %REGLA_5
accion("DORMIR"):-es_principal(libro,no),es_principal(libro,no). %REGLA_6

%HECHOS
es_principal(libro,si).

goal
accion(X).
```

Lamentablemente, no me sale resultado, sino me sale lo siguiente:

```
E;Test_Goal, pos:534, 415 Clauses for the same predicate should be grouped es_principal
```

Entiendo que se deba agrupar, pero traté de separarlos para un mayor orden y el problema me indica que se debe separar los hechos de las clausulas. ¿Cómo puedo mejorar mi código usando variables en las clausulas?.

De antemano, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Cuando preguntas `¿Cómo puedo mejorar mi código?` estás buscando respuestas basadas en opiniones. Por favor revisa: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Hice el siguiente codigo en [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) que podria ayudarte a empezar.

```
es_libro(no,_,_,si).
es_libro(_,no,_,si).
es_libro(_,_,_,no):-!.

lee_condiciones(Pelota,Mando,Arco):-
    write('es pelota de basket?si/no'),
    nl,
    read(Pelota),
    write('es mando?si/no'),
    nl,
    read(Mando),
    write('es arco?si/no'),
    nl,
    read(Arco).

determina_accion(Pelota,Mando,Arco,Accion):-
    es_libro(Pelota,Mando,Arco,Libritud),
    Libritud == si
    , Accion = 'LeerLibros'.

determina_accion(Pelota,Mando,Arco,Accion):-
    es_libro(Pelota,Mando,Arco,Libritud),
    Libritud == no,
    Pelota == si,
    Accion = 'Jugar basket'.


determina_accion('Dormir'):-!.

miprograma(Accion):-  lee_condiciones(Pelota,Mando,Arco), determina_accion(Pelota,Mando,Arco,Accion).
```

Como veras hay varias secciones en el codigo, la primera es la base de datos o los hechos.

Son las condiciones de respuesta que se usan para decidir.

Posteriormente vienen las reglas, y para ello cabe hacer notar que los parametros de las reglas pueden estar o no definidos, y por lo mismo uno o mas de ellos podrian ser el resultado.

Un patron comun es hacer reglas del tipo

```
es_cualquiercosa(Condicion1,Condicion2, Resultado).
```

con la particularidad de que si tu definicion es muy buena se pueden inferir los valores en cualquier orden, por ejemplo teniendo:

```
suma(Sumando1, Sumando2, Sumatoria):- Sumatoria is Sumando1 + Sumando2.
```

podemos consultar de varias maneras por ejemplo

```
suma(2, 2, Sumatoria).
```

De la solucion particular

> Sumatoria: 4

```
suma(Sumando1, 2, 5).
```

> Sumando1: 3

```
suma(2, Sumando2, 6).
```

> Sumando2: 4

Por ello las primeras tres lineas de tu pseudocodigo se convierten en la base de datos.

las ultimas 3 se convierten en una regla ya que en las tres se busca determinar el valor de accion.

En swipl para leer un termino se usa read/1.
Para escribir un mensaje se usa write.
Para el salto de linea se usa nl.